# how to use a pointer point to map<int, order> and map<int,order,greater<>> in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, instantiation

I want to use a pointer pointing to both `map<int,order>` and `map<int,order,greater<>>`.

In the below code, the pointer will point to someone based on a flag. But the code can't compile successfully.

the reason for doing this, i need to update the map based asc order or desc order. all update operations are the same except the order of iteration.the update operations are accumulative sum.

So, how to do this?

```
using namespace std;
struct order {
    int qty;
    int sum;
};
void updateOpr(map<int, order >* pmap) {
    order* pre = nullptr;
    for (auto& [key, value] : *pmap) {
        if (pre == nullptr) {
            value.sum = value.qty;
        }
        else {
            //todo some thing
            value.sum = pre->sum + value.qty;
        }
        pre = &value;;
    }
}
int main() {
    map<int, order, greater<>> imap1;
    map<int, order > imap2;
    map<int, order >* pmap = nullptr;
    bool flag = true;
    if (flag) {
        pmap = &imap1;
    }
    else {
        pmap = &imap2;
    }

    int key = 10;
    if (pmap->contains(key)) {
        //todo some thing;
    }

    updateOpr(pmap);
}
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this technique?

Comment: `map<int,int>` and `map<int,int,greater<>>` are distinct types .... You can use `void *`, but I wouldn't recommend it (and probably wouldn't work for whatever it is you're trying to do). Maybe you should describe what you are trying to do / solve, then it would be easier to provide a more helpful answer.

Comment: As mentioned above these are 2 separate types. You can try `std::variant`.

Comment: Unfortunately in c++ templated types of the same class with different parameters are completely unrelated to each other and can't be assigned to the same variable unless there is some common base class (which there isn't in this case)

Comment: `variant<monostate, decltype(imap1)*, decltype(imap2)*> p2;`

Comment: A side note: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  If we showed you how to get this code to compile, you would have a program that does nothing.

Comment: to explain my purpose clearly, i have modified my question. to put it simply, i need to do some operation on the map, the operations are all the same except the loop order.

Answer (score 2):

The types are distinct and have no common base class, so you can't do that.

Templates are useful for this kind of situation, when things look alike but aren't related.

Move the code that uses the map to a function template, then create a different map depending on what you want and pass it to the function.

Something like this:

```
template<typename Map>
void do_the_work(Map& m)
{
    // Work with m
}


int main() {
    bool flag = true;
    if (flag) {
        map<int, int, greater<>> imap;
        do_the_work(imap);
    }
    else {
        map<int, int> imap;
        do_the_work(imap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I must say, I don't understand why commenters suggest that variant is the only option. It can be done quite easily by changing maps into the same type:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() {
    using CompareType = std::function<bool(int, int)>;
    using MapType = std::map<int, int, CompareType>;

    MapType mapAscending{std::less<int>{}};
    MapType mapDescending{std::greater<int>{}};
    MapType* mapPtr = nullptr;

    bool shouldBeDescending;
    std::cin >> shouldBeDescending;

    if (shouldBeDescending) {
        mapPtr = &mapDescending;
    } else {
        mapPtr = &mapAscending;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but the performance is an issue. `int<int` and `int>int` are both about one CPU instruction. `std::function` is about two orders of magnitude more expensive. And you pay that prices for every comparison. You'd be better off by encapsulating the `std::map` in two classes sharing a single base class interface. That way, the dynamic dispatch happens only once per operation.

Comment: @MSalters or just use a raw function pointer, std:: function isn't necessary here for a stateless comparator